# How to mock an object that is already being instantiated within the code of the class to be tested and write stubs for it?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

The class I need to test will look somewhat similar to this. I am not writing the actual class here.

```
public class Client {

private String country;
private ConnectionImpl conn;

public Client (String country){
    this.country = country;
}

private ConnectionImpl createConnection() {
  SetConnectionImpl impl = new SetConnectionImpl() {
    public String getFirstName() {
      return "Some value";
    }
    public String getLastName() {
      return "Some value";
    }
    public String getAddress() {
      return "Some value";
    }
    public String getPhoneNumber() {
      return "Some value";
    }};
  return new ConnectionImpl("", "", "", "", impl);
}

public String letsDoSomeWork(String requestObject) {
  final ConnectionImpl impl = createConnection();
  String letsHaveSomeResponse = 
  impl.methodTobeStubbed(requestObject);
  return letsHaveSomeResponse;
}
}
```

Now the test class that I have written will look like this. I am using mockito to write stubs.

```
@Runwith(MockitoJunitRunner.class)
public class ClientTest {
@Mock
ConnectionImpl impl;

private Client client;
@Before()
public void initialize() {
client = new Client("India");
}

@Test
public void testLetsDoSomework_ShouldReturnString() {
String request = "request";
when(impl.methodTobeStubbed(request)).thenReturn("Response");
String letsHaveSomeResponse = client.letsDoSomeWork(request);
//Now I will make Assertions
}
```

}

Unfortunately this stubbing doesn't work and my assumption is that since the class to be tested is internally creating an "impl" object, the mock object that I am creating here is not being considered. So in the end the code is entering the "impl" class which it should not.

```
when(impl.methodTobeStubbed(request)).thenReturn("Response");
```

Comment: The short answer is: use PowerMock(-itgo). - The better answer is: do not instantiate the `ConnectionImpl` within your code under test. Use *dependency injection* and pass in the  `ConnectionImpl` instance e.g. as a parameter of the constructor.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle True I too felt it should be passed throught the constructor as it would make everyone's life easy but unfortunately my team has used this kind of approach and am simply writing test cases for the code they have written.

I also  tried the WhiteBox method from PowerMockito and tried calling the createConnection() method directly into my mock object created in the test case. But the stubbing acts wierd. Instead of returning the response, the stub directly took me inside the dependency class.

Comment: *"unfortunately my team has used this kind of approach and am simply writing test cases"* Are you the dedicated "tester" of the team? Are you in a position to  refuse to write this test or  acquire the permission to refactor it?

Comment: _"Are you the dedicated "tester" of the team?"_ Actually yes I am. I have requested permission to refactor it. Let me see how it goes. But apart from refactoring, if you can suggest another way, please let me know.

Comment: Without permission to refactor your only option is *PowerMock(-ito)*. I'm in the lucky position not to use it. - However: in an ideal world you as the tester should not write the unit tests, the developers should. But this is off topic here. You could ask at the [workplace site](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/) how to deal with that in your situation.

Comment: I did and power mock is the solution. I made the code to work. But I am not getting code coverage as JaCoCo and PowerMock doesn't mix well together. So after hours of trying, am think of using some other code coverage that can detect PowerMock. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 2):

I made the test case to work. Here is what I did.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Client.class)
public class ClientTest {

@Mock
ConnectionImpl impl;

private Client client;
@Before()
public void initialize() {
    client = PowerMockito.spy(new Client("India"));
    doReturn(impl).when(client, "createConnection");
}

@Test
public void testLetsDoSomework_ShouldReturnString() {
    String request = "request";
    when(impl.methodTobeStubbed(request)).thenReturn("Response");
    String letsHaveSomeResponse = client.letsDoSomeWork(request);
//Now I will make Assertions
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make `createConnection` method return your mocked connection.

First, change the method to `protected`:

```
protected ConnectionImpl createConnection() {
    .... // same code
}
```

If the method is private, you can't mock it in your test.

Then, in your test, make a spy with the `Client` object, using `Mockito.spy` method:

```
@Before()
public void initialize() {
    client = Mockito.spy(new Client("India"));

    // letsDoSomeWork method will be called (instead of a mocked version)
    when(client.letsDoSomeWork(anyString())).thenCallRealMethod();

    // createConnection returns your mocked impl object (it doesn't compile if createConnection method is private)
    when(client.createConnection()).thenReturn(impl);
}
```

Then, when you call `letsDoSomeWork`, it will call the real method in `Client` class. So, `createConnection` will be called - and as it's mocked, it will return the mocked `impl` object.

Note: make sure that `ClientTest` class is in the same package of `Client` class, in order to make `createConnection` visible by the test (even if they are in different source folders - like `src/main` and `src/test`, assuming you're using maven or similar - the package name must be the same)

---

Another way of doing it is to make a setter method for the connection:

```
public class Client {

    private String country;

    private ConnectionImpl conn;

    public Client(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    // create setter method for connection    
    public void setConn(ConnectionImpl conn) {
        this.conn = conn;
    }

    public String letsDoSomeWork(String requestObject) {
        // no need to createConnection
        String letsHaveSomeResponse = 
        this.conn.methodTobeStubbed(requestObject);
        return letsHaveSomeResponse;
    }
}
```

So your test will be like:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ClientTest {

    @Mock
    MyConn impl;

    private Client client;

    @Before
    public void initialize() {
        client = new Client("India");
        client.setConn(impl);
    }

    @Test
    public void testLetsDoSomework_ShouldReturnString() {
        String request = "request";
        when(impl.methodTobeStubbed(request)).thenReturn("Response");

        String letsHaveSomeResponse = client.letsDoSomeWork(request);

        // do assertions
    }
}
```

---

Or even better, make a constructor that receives the connection:

```
public Client(String country, ConnectionImpl conn) {
    this.country = country;
    this.conn = conn;
}
```

And in the test class:

```
@Before
public void initialize() {
    client = new Client("India", impl);
}
```

Comment: But I don't want it to call the real method. I have already created a response. I want Mockito to send me back the response without calling the real method.

Comment: If you mock `letsDoSomeWork`, you don't need to mock `impl` because it won't be used. If you want to mock `impl` and use it, you need to call `letsDoSomeWork` because that's where `impl` is used.

Comment: Actually this is what I recommended my team but I got a firm no.